# Android auto generated stuff in eclipse

Tags: android, linux, auto-generate

Im currently working on Android SDK. I have some applications that I need to move from Windows to Ubuntu.

Will I be able to move the projectfiles that I have created? Will the v3,v4,v7 etc that are generated be re-generated when run in Eclipse on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can move projects between eclipse environments (and OSes) without issue.

Copy the entire project folder (including the .project and other files).